# Meteor - can a template have multiple autoruns in an onCreated, with different reactivity dependencies?

Tags: javascript, meteor

In a Meteor template's `onCreated` function, can there be multiple autoruns as such:

```
Template.componentA.onCreated(function() {

  this.autorun(() => {
    const varX = Session.get('varX');
    // block X
  });

  this.autorun(() => {
    const varY = Session.get('varY');
    // block Y
  });

});
```

And specifically, will they each handle reactivity dependencies separately?

(so that I'm not rerunning block Y every time the session variable 'varX' changes, and I'm not rerunning block X every time session variable 'varY' changes)

Comment: Why don't you just try it? Could be faster than waiting for an answer here ;-)

Comment: @JesperWe I do both :D If I can't figure something out initially, formulating the question makes me think critically about exactly what I'm asking, and I continue to work on finding the answer myself in the mean time once I've posted my question.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can attach both to `this` since the second might override the first. You might need to use a `Tracker.autorun()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each declared autorun function will look for reactive data source changes to trigger itself ([meteor doc](https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html)). So you can clearly use different autoruns.

Here is demo code to test it.

```
this.autorun(function () {
    // a call to Session.set("test",1) will trigger the autorun
    var test = Session.get("test");
    console.log("autorun test");
});

this.autorun(function () {
    // a call to Session.set("test2",2) will trigger the autorun
    var test = Session.get("test2");
    console.log("autorun test2");
});
```

you can then test in console, and here is the output:

```
Session.set("test",1)
>undefined
>landing.js:148 autorun test
Session.set("test2",1)
>undefined
>landing.js:153 autorun test2
```

To handle data sources that shouldn't trigger the autorun, use [Tracker.nonreactive](https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#Tracker-nonreactive)

Comment: I just did a test in Meteor 1.5.1 and the two `autoruns` are combined and one triggers the other. I had to use a different "helper" template.  I needed to subscribe to a `Session` var but when I did, it rebuilt my whole app because the same parent template `autorun` was driving all the child templates. So if the `Session` was mixed in, it reran everything.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are doing @evolross ? I don't understand your point without code example

Answer (score 1):

Meteor will put whatever declared in the various autoruns inside the same function, so there is no difference if you split them. 
To achieve separated reactivity consider creating two different components.

Comment: If I remember correctly, I tested it and that was not the case. The indivudal autoruns were reactive on different data. I think Victor's answer is correct.

Comment: Have you tried the example provided in my answer ? @evolross

Comment: I stand corrected. Just tested it again and indeed, different `autoruns` are respected per template. My bad.